# Rails model singularize not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Mongoid model called "GradebookSettings". I've gone into inflections and added:

> inflect.singular("GradebookSettings", "GradebookSettings")

When I go into irb, it properly singularizes "GradebookSettings" to "GradebookSettings". However, when I try to access an associated model, it keeps trying to singularize it to GradebookSetting.

I am using Mongoid. I am tempted to pluralize GradebookSettings with two s' but I'd rather not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to trick the inflector. Use the `:class_name` option of the association to set the class instead:

```
embeds_many :gbsettings, :class_name => "GradebookSettings"
```